# Guises of the Stasheff polytopes, associahedra for the Coxeter $A_n$ root system?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, moduli-spaces, convex-polytopes

Richard Stanley keeps a famous running compilation of different guises of the celebrated Catalan numbers. The number of vertices of the associahedron is one instantiation among the multitude, and the associahedra themselves occur in many guises, so in some sense they are a multi-dimensional, geometric extension of the Catalans, that also pop up in a surprising variety of places (for a quick intro, see Jon McCammond, "[Noncrossing partitions in surprising places](http://www.math.ucsb.edu/%7Ejon.mccammond/papers/nc-survey-official.pdf)").

> Is there a compilation for the associahedra, like Richard Stanley's for the Catalans?
>
> If not, what guises are you aware of?

Examples are relations to

**1) Partial orderings of partial associations of a list**

Reflected in the face structure of the associahedra, as described in McCammond's article.

**2) Partition polynomials for Lagrange (compositional) inversion of functions or formal power series and so to iterated "Lie" derivatives**

The partition polynomials are isomorphic to the face structure of the associahedra, see "[The multiple facets of the associahedron](http://www2.maths.ox.ac.uk/cmi/library/academy/LectureNotes05/Lodaypaper.pdf)" by J. Loday, and can be generated by an iterated (Lie) derivative $[d/df(x)]^n$, where $f$ is expressed in the indeterminates of a power series, or o.g.f., ([OEIS-A133437](https://oeis.org/A133437), [OEIS-A145271](https://oeis.org/A145271)).

**3) Classification of separation coordinates/variables for the Hamilton-Jacobi equations**

In "[Separation coordinates, moduli spaces and Stasheff polytopes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.6132)" by K. Schobel and P. Veselov (nice figures!), the combinatorics of the polytopes tessellating the real version of the Deligne-Mumford-Knudsen moduli space $\bar{M}_{0,n+2}(R)$ of stable curves of genus zero with $n + 2$ marked points are used to describe the topology and algebraic geometry of the space of separation coordinates on the spheres $S^n$ and to classify the different canonical forms of these coordinates, or separation variables, for the Hamilton-Jacobi equation.

**4) Diagonalization of convex polygons into non-overlapping convex sub-polygons**

See the beautifully illustrated book *Discrete and Computational Geometry* (pg. 74) by S. Devadoss and J. O'Rourke. Also "[Polygonal dissections and reversion of series](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7194)" by A. Schuetz and G. Whieldon.

**5) Secondary polytopes--convex hull of the area vectors of all triangulations of a convex polygon**

See Devadoss and O'Rourke, pg. 79.

**6) The Fulton-MacPherson compactification space of the configuration space of n particles colliding on an interval--truncated simplices**

See D and O, pg. 241. Nested tubings also.

**7) Deformation of bordered surfaces with marked points**

See "[Deformations of bordered surfaces and convex polytopes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.1676)" by S. Devadoss, T. Heath, and W. Vipismikul.

**8) Cluster A algebras and coordinates for scattering amplitudes**

See "[Cluster polylogarithms for scattering amplitudes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.6446)" by J. Golden, M. Paulos, M. Spradlin, and A. Vlolovich.

**9) Schroeder lattice paths (marked Dyck paths, [OEIS A126216](https://oeis.org/A126216))**

Enumerated by f-vectors of the associahedra [A126216] = [[A001263]](https://oeis.org/A001263)[[A007318]](https://oeis.org/A007318)= Narayana * Pascal $= [N][P]$ as lower triangular matrices.

**10) Solutions to the inviscid Hopf-Burgers equation**

See "[Toric topology of the Stasheff polytopes](http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/998/01/covered/MIMS_ep2007_232.pdf)" by V. Buchstaber and also [MO-Q145555](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145555/why-is-there-a-connection-between-enumerative-geometry-and-nonlinear-waves).

**11) Coinverse (antipode) for a Hopf algebra**

Analogous to the Faa di Bruno Hopf algebra, but represented in the indeterminates of a power series/ordinary generating function rather than those of a Taylor series/exponential generating function. Then the coproduct is related to Lah partition polynomials rather than Bell partition polynomials and the antipode, to Lagrange inversion/series reversion for o.g.f.s and therefore to associahedra rather than e.g.f.s. and Whitehouse simplicial complexes. For the usual e.g.f. formulation of the Faa di Bruno Hopf algebra, see *[Quantum Field Theory II Quantum Electrodynamics](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0408145)* (pg. 136) by E. Zeidler or "Combinatorial Hopf algebras in quantum field theory I" by H. Figueroa and J. Gracia-Bondi.

**12) The shifted reciprocal of the o.g.f. of the refined Euler characteristic partition polynomials of the associahedra give the formal free cumulants of free probability theory, and the polynomials are proportional to a partial derivative of the free cumulants** (added 1/20/22)

See [the MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412573/combinatorics-for-the-action-of-virasoro-kac-schwarz-operators-partition-poly) "Combinatorics for the action of Virasoro / Kac–Schwarz operators: partition polynomials of free probability theory".

**13) The associahedra and noncrossing partitions are dual geometric and analytic constructs** (Added 7/19/2022)

The signed generalization/refinement of item 9 above is $[A] = [N][R] =$ [[A133437](https://oeis.org/A133437)] = [[A111785](https://oeis.org/A111785)] = [[A134264](https://oeis.org/A134264)][signed [A263633](https://oeis.org/A263633)], where, e.g., $[R][a]$ represents substitution of the infinite set of indeterminates $(a_1,a_2,...)$ for those of the reciprocal partition polynomials (for o.g.f.s) defined by $x/f(x) = 1/(1+c_1x+c_2x^2 + \cdots) = R_0 + R_1(c_1) x + R_2(c_1,c_2) x^2 + \cdots$; the set of partition polynomials of $[A]$ are the refined Euler characteristic polynomials for the associahedra; and $[N]$, the refined Narayana, or noncrossing partition, polynomials. (The indeterminates and partition polynomials of the associahedra polynomials A1334347 must be re-indexed, i.e., shifted by -1, with (1') = 1.) Note $[R]^2 =[I]=[A]^2$ is the identity transformation under indeterminate substitution/composition, so also $[A][R] = [N]$.

In addition, $[I]=[A][R][R][A] = [N][R][A] = [R][A][A][R] = [R][A][N]  $ implies $[R][A] = [N]^{-1}$, the inverse of $[N]$. The pair of inverses define the free moments and cumulants of free probability theory in terms of each other, so we can connect the associahedra to free probability as well along with its connections to random matrix theory and quantum fields.

The e.g.f. equivalent is $[L] = [E][P]$, where $[L]$ is the set of classic Lagrange inversion polynomials [A134685](https://oeis.org/A134685), associated with weighted phylogenetic trees; $[E]$, the refined Eulerian polynomials [A145271](https://oeis.org/A145271); and $[P]$, the refined Euler characteristic polynomials $P_n(d_1,...,d_n)$ [A133314](https://oeis.org/A133314) of the permutahedra, giving the Taylor series coefficients of the reciprocal $1/h(x)$ of the e.g.f. $h(x) = 1 + d_1 x +d_2 \frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots.$ We have a dual set of generators $[E]$ and $[E]^{-1}$ for an infinite group as well since $[L]^2 = [I] = [P]^2$.

The two sets of compositional inversion polynomials $[L]$ and $[A]$ are related by a simple scaling of the indeterminates by the factorials just as formal e.g.f.s are related to formal o.g.f.s--a simple Borel-Laplace transform term by term--and so are the sets of multiplicative inversion polynomials $[R]$ and $[P]$ .

From the four sets of partition polynomials $[A]$,$[L]$,$[N]$, and $[E]$ issue compositional inverses of series while from $[R]$ and $[P]$, multiplicative inverses. This equivalence is the integrating thread of a tapestry of geometric/topological and algebraic/analytic constructs from polytopes and trees to moduli spaces, punctured Riemann surfaces, and characteristic classes to quadratic operads and Lie derivatives/infinitesimal generators (and, naturally, up on the tapestry is quantum physics, e.g., see [this MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425283/combinatorics-of-iterated-composition-of-noncrossing-partition-polynomials)).

---

(Each topic could be elaborated upon. The links in the OEIS refer to algebras I'm not comfortable with. Please feel free to do so in an answer.)

I know several examples, the third being the most recent I've come across, but there are others who frequent this site who can easily state more accurately and succinctly than I other connections of the associahedra to operads, spaces homotopically equivalent to loop spaces, trees, dendriform algebra, moduli spaces, ... .

Comment: The simplicial dual and the h-vectors also pop up in interesting places, and if you re-scale the indeterminates of the o.g.f. for the Lagrange inversion to generate an e.g.f. formulation, the Whitehouse simplicial complexes, tropical Grassmannians, and phylogenetic trees sprout up (expressing the inversion in terms of the indeterminates of the reciprocal of the function introduces the Narayana h-vectors), so it's a skip and a hopf from the associahedra to other complexes and classic number arrays.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6373/combinatorics-of-the-stasheff-polytopes

Comment: More: "The brick polytopes of a sorting network" by Pilaud and Santos  (https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2731) and " Noncrossing hypertrees" by McCammond .

Comment: "Cluster algebras: an introduction" by Williams (pg. 7) https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6263

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194888/inversion-koszul-duality-combinatorics-and-geometry

Comment: See "Hopf monoids and generalized permutohedra" by Aguiar and Ardila https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.07504

Comment: "On Young diagrams, flips and cluster algebras of type A" by Mikhail Gorsky (https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.2458).

Comment: See "Cluster Algebras" by Leclerc and Williams http://www.pnas.org/content/111/27/9676.full

Comment: See "Stokes sets" by Baryshnikov http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~ymb/texts/stokes.pdf

Comment: See refs in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182622/an-intriguing-tapestry-number-triangles-polytopes-grassmannians-and-scatteri

Comment: See "Posets arising as 1-skeleta of simple polytopes, the nonrevisiting path conjecture, and poset topology" by Patricia Hersh https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.04342

Comment: See the presentation "The Associahedron and its Friends" by V. Pilaud, Seminaire Lotharingien de Combinatoire, April 4 – 6, 2016 https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~slc/wpapers/s76vortrag/pilaud.pdf

Comment: See "Positive Grassmannian and Polyhedral Subdivisions" by Postnikov, pg. 17, https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.05307, and "Combinatorics of Polytopes" by A. Barvinok, https://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~barvinok/polynotes669.pdf

Comment: See "Scattering Forms from Geometries at Infinity" by S. He https://indico.ipmu.jp/indico/event/145/contributions/2231/attachments/1886/2248/talk_IPMUSong_He.pdf

Comment: Cluster Polylogarithms for Scattering Amplitudes
by Golden, Paulos, Spradlin https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.6446

Comment: History of the Associahedron by Escobar https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~lescobar/pdf/Olivetti2015.pdf

Comment: "Properties of scattering forms and their relation to
associahedra" by de la Cruz, Kniss, and Weinzierl https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.07942

Comment: See Theorem 16 of http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/parkpoly.pdf for a connection with the so-called Pitman-Stanley polytope.

Comment: See "The diagonal of the associahedra" by
Naruki Masuda, Hugh Thomas, Andy Tonks, Bruno Vallette https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.08059

Comment: "Topological invariants from higher category theory" by. Gurski, Johnson, and Osorno http://www.ams.org/journals/notices/201908/rnoti-p1225.pdf

Comment: A relation to the algebra of oriented simplices presented in Deep Beauty edited by Halvorson and in "The algebra of oriented simplexes" by Ross Street https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002240498790137X

Comment: "Configuration spaces from Combinatorial,Topological and Categorical Perspectives" by Batanin http://www.math.mq.edu.au/~street/BatanAustMSMq.pdf

Comment: The number of inequivalent weakly admissible Wilson loop diagrams on n is the number of non-parallel faces in the associahedron An. -- From "Combinatorics of the geometry of Wilson loop diagrams I:
equivalence classes via matroids and polytopes" by Susama Agarwala, Sian Fryer, and Karen Yeats  https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.10919

Comment: "Lie Polynomials and a Twistorial Correspondence for Amplitudes" by Hadleigh Frost, Lionel Mason https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.04198 and "ABHY Associahedra and Newton polytopes of F-polynomials for finite type cluster algebras"  by Véronique Bazier-Matte, Guillaume Douville, Kaveh Mousavand, Hugh Thomas, Emine Yıldırım (https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.09986)

Comment: "The Duality Between Color and Kinematics and its Applications" by Zvi Bern et al. (https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.01358)

Comment: "The tropical totally positive Grassmannian" by Speyer and Williams https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0312297

Comment: "Causal Diamonds, Cluster Polytopes and Scattering Amplitudes" by Arkani-Hamed, He, Salvatori, and Thomas https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.12948

Comment: "An Etude on Recursion Relations and Triangulations" by He and Yang https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.08508

Comment: "Anyons in an exactly solved model and beyond" by Alexei Kitaev (https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0506438) relates associahedra to MacLane’s coherence theorem.

Comment: "MultipIe $\zeta$–motives and moduli spaces $\bar{M}_{0,n}$" by Goncharov and Manin https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0204102

Comment: "Positive configuration space" by
Nima Arkani-Hamed, Thomas Lam, Marcus Spradlin https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.03904

Comment: "Generalized cluster complexes and Coxeter combinatorics" by Sergey Fomin, Nathan Reading https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0505085

Comment: From p. 33 of "The odd origin of Gerstenhaber brackets, Batalin-Vilkovisky operators, and master equations" by Kaufmann, Ward, and Zuniga: "The Stasheff polytopes are also a geometric incarnation of the master equation" -- an  equation the action must satisfy in a quantum field string theory. (https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.5543)

Comment: "The associahedron as a holographic entanglement polytope" by Levay https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.03823

Comment: "Braid groups, cluster, and free probability: An outline from the AIM Workshop, January 2005" and "Generalized Noncrossing Partitions
and Combinatorics of Coxeter Groups" by Drew Armstrong.

Comment: "Associahedra, Tamari Lattices and Related Structures: Tamari Memorial Festschrift" (eds) Müller-Hoissen, Pollo, Stasheff

Comment: "Geometry of the Space of Phylogenetic Trees" by Billera, Holmes, and Vogtmann and "The Tropical Grassmannian" by Speyer and Sturmfels.

Comment: "The permutoassociahedron, Mac Lane’s coherence theoremand asymptotic zones for the KZ equation" by Kapranov.

Comment: "Realizing the associahedron: Mysteries and questions" by Ceballos and Ziegler (https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.4059).

Comment: "Associahedra minimize f-vectors of secondary polytopes of planar point sets" by Antonio Fernández, Francisco Santos https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.00544

Comment: "Guillotine Partitions and the Hipparchus Operad" by John Baez (https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2022/12/guillotine_partitions_and_the.html#more) and "Higher Operads, Higher Categories" by Tom Leinster (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305049),,

Comment: "Colorful graph associahedra" by Devadoss and Smith.

Comment: The equivalent antipode, i.e., an explicit non-commutative Lagrange formula, for the Hopf algebra for which the indeterminates do not commute is given on p. 14 of "Non-commutative Hopf algebra of formal diffeomorphisms" by Brouder, Frabetti, and Krattenthaler (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0406117).

Comment: "Signed tree associahedra" by Pilaud http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/Labo/Vincent.Pilaud/documents/publications/Pilaud_SignedTreeAssociahedra.pdf

Comment: "Associahedra to $\infty$ and beyond" by Stasheff (slides) https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~vdots/HMI2017Stasheff.pdf

Comment: Recent survey: "Celebrating Loday's Associahedron" by Vincent Pilaud, Francisco Santos, Günter M. Ziegler https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.08471

Comment: "Moduli of J-Holomorphic Curves with Lagrangian Boundary Conditions and Open Gromov-Witten Invariants for an S1-Equivariant Pair" by Chiu-Chu Melissa Liu https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0210257

Comment: "Associahedra minimize f-vectors of secondary polytopes of planar point sets" by
Antonio Fernández and Francisco Santos https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.00544.

Comment: "Equivalence Between Four Models of Associahedra" by
Somnath Basu and Sandip Samanta (https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.04847)

Answer (score 6):

If $Q$ is the quiver $A_n$ with linear orientation, then the Stasheff associahedron appears as the polytope with vertices the basic tilting $kQ$-modules and faces the faithful basic exceptional $kQ$-modules. The partial order on faces is defined by $M \leq N$ whenever $N$ is a a direct summand of $M$. This gives a poset isomorphic to the one in your first example.

References:

Buan, Aslak Bakke; Krause, Henning. [Tilting and cotilting for quivers of type $\tilde A_n$](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404903002767), section 3 and appendix A.

Buan, Aslak Bakke; Marsh, Robert; Reineke, Markus; Reiten, Idun; Todorov, Gordana. [Tilting theory and cluster combinatorics](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870805001763), section 4.

Comment: The cluster story continues from there to combinatorics in http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1108.1776 "Subword complexes, cluster complexes, and generalized multi-associahedra" and then to geometry in http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1404.4671 "Brick manifolds and toric varieties of brick polytopes".

Comment: I don't know much more than what you wrote, that the associative operad is Koszul self-dual. I wonder if this could be read off as a combinatorial property of the associahedra? It's better to let someone else answer this.

Comment: There is natural bijection between rooted planar binary trees and tilting modules for the quivers if I read Chapoton correctly.

Comment: @AllenKnutson : and there is even more to that, I am happy to say: http://arxiv.org/abs/1510.03261 .

Comment: The link in the previous comment is to "Toric varieties of Loday's associahedra and noncommutative cohomological field theories" by Dotsenko,  Shadrin, and Vallette.

Comment: Interestingly, quivers are also associated to the permutohedra, the polytopes whose Euler characteristics are related to multiplicative inversion. See "Physics and mathematics of graded quivers" by Hasan (and work with Franco) https://academicworks.cuny.edu/gc_etds/3321/

Answer (score 2):

One direct way the associahedra give rise to a generalization of Catalan numbers is perhaps worth mentioning. While the latter are $\frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!n!}$, the number of faces of shape $S_1^{n_1}\times S_2^{n_2}\times S_3^{n_3}\times\cdots$ in $S_n:=$ the $n-1$-dimensional Stasheff polytope, where $n=n_1+n_2+n_3+...$, is equal to $\frac{(2n_1+3n_2+4n_3+...)!}{(n_1+2n_2+3n_3+...+1)!n_1!n_2!n_3!\cdots}$.

The first appearance of thеse numbers that I know I learned from the [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/144821/41291) by Ira Gessel to the question ["MultiCatalan numbers"](https://mathoverflow.net/q/144790/41291) - it seems to be [W. T. Tutte, The number of planted plane trees with a given partition. Amer. Math. Monthly 71 (1964) 272–277](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2312183) (although there is no mention of polytopes there).

**Later** - as suggested by Tom Copeland I am adding one reference from one of my comments here too: M. Kapranov and M. Saito ["Hidden Stasheff polytopes in algebraic K-theory and in the space of Morse functions"](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0192/K3.pdf) (K-theory preprint archive, May 1997) contains an intriguing and, as far as I know, still not fully understood connection between associahedra and Steinberg relations. Briefly, the key relation $[e_{ij}(a),e_{jk}(b)]=e_{ik}(ab)$ appears as a pentagon in a cell complex encoding homologies of general linear groups; higher relations similarly contributing to higher homologies can be arranged into Stasheff polytopes. That paper also describes appearance of associahedra encoding catastrophes leading to interactions between critical points of generic Morse functions.

Comment: Given Cayley's familiarity with Catalans as a generating series for enumerating certain forests of trees and the dissections of polygons,  his use of analytic trees to model iterated derivatives (operandators), and his, Sylvester's, and Graves' work on normal ordering of differential operators, it's surprising that he didn't discover these numbers through the connection between iterated derivatives and Lagrange inversion, which he frequently used. (Or maybe he did.)

Comment: @TomCopeland Btw I was always puzzled (and disappointed) by the fact that none of the handbooks like Abramowitz & Stegun, Gradshtejn & Ryzhik, Janke-Emde-Lösch, Dwight, etc. mention any explicit formulas for coefficients of formal series reverses (or inverses, logarithms, exponents, composites, etc. for that matter)

Comment: Composites are noted in A & S (see partitions), but generally you are right. Around 1857, Graves wrote down the relation between iterated derivatives and inversion (no expansion?). Maybe it wasn't until Boltzmann intro. stat mech and Feynman, his diagrams that combinatorics really started to be noticed in physics (aside from the dalliance with knots and vortices/atoms) whereas special fcts. had been around in a central role. When and why Bruno-like partitions nudged their way onto the stage, I don'know (maybe cumulants and cluster expansions in stat mech), but they are in A&S.

Comment: The Kirkman(1857)-Cayley(1890) numbers in fact generate the number of faces of the associahedra, what you call the multiCatalan numbers.

Comment: @TomCopeland Wow, that's interesting! Will have a look...

Comment: Dwight is referenced in Mathworld under 'series reversion' and also the classic book by Morse and Feshbach, which is frequently a great ref for geometric insights behind the analytics of the topics they discuss.

Comment: Newton himself derived the formal inverse of power series (o.g.f.s), and, therefore, at least, the first few of the refined face polynomials of the associahedra. I don't know if he had a general formula for the coefficients, but he was a master at computation and binomial coefficients, so I wouldn't bet against it.

Comment: For a nice presentation of some history of the Catalan numbers, Fuss-Catalan-Segner numbers, and the associahedra, see "Catalan numbers: From EGS to BEG" by Drew Armstrong http://www.math.miami.edu/~armstrong/Talks/catalan_at_mit.pdf

Answer (score 1):

From "Scattering Forms and the Positive Geometry of
Kinematics, Color and the Worldsheet" ([arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.09102)) by Nima Arkani-Hamed, Yuntao Bai, Song He, and Gongwang Yan:

The search for a theory of the S-Matrix has revealed surprising geometric structures underlying amplitudes ranging from the worldsheet to the amplituhedron, but these are all geometries in auxiliary spaces as opposed to kinematic space where amplitudes live. In this paper, we propose a novel geometric understanding of amplitudes for a large class of theories. The key idea is to think of  amplitudes not as functions, but rather as differential forms on kinematic space. We explore the resulting picture for a wide range of massless theories in general spacetime dimensions. For the bi-adjoint $\phi~^3$ in scalar theory, we establish a direct connection between its “scattering form” and a classic polytope—the associahedron—known to mathematicians since the 1960’s. We find an associahedron living naturally in kinematic space, and the tree level amplitude is simply the “canonical form” associated with this “positive geometry”. Fundamental physical properties such as locality and unitarity, as well as novel “soft” limits, are fully determined by the combinatorial geometry of this polytope. Furthermore, the moduli space for the open string worldsheet has also long been recognized as an associahedron. We show that the scattering equations act as a diffeomorphism between the interior of this old “worldsheet associahedron” and the new “kinematic associahedron”, providing a geometric interpretation and simple conceptual derivation of the bi-adjoint CHY formula.

Comment: "Positive configuration space" by
Nima Arkani-Hamed, Thomas Lam, Marcus Spradlin https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.03904

Comment: "Amplituhedra, and Beyond" by Ferro and Lukowski https://inspirehep.net/literature/1806037

Comment: See also "A Contour Integral Representation for the Dual Five-Point Function and a Symmetry of the Genus Four Surface in R6" by Hanson and Sha  https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0510064 on relations among associahedra, string theory, cross-ratios, the Pochhammer contour, and projective spaces.

Comment: "Stringy canonical forms" by
Nima Arkani-Hamed, Song He, and Thomas Lam https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.08707 and "Binary Geometries, Generalized Particles and Strings, and Cluster Algebras" by Nima Arkani-Hamed, Song He, Thomas Lam, and Hugh Thomas https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.11764

Comment: "Dissection Quivers, Polytopes and Scattering Amplitudes" by Alok Laddha https://iip.ufrn.br/media/pdf/fast_AlokLaddha_iip_ictp_2020_5.pdf and "Towards Positive Geometry of Multi Scalar Field Amplitudes: Accordiohedron and Effective Field Theory" by Mrunmay Jagadale and Alok Laddha https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.04915

Comment: "Scattering amplitudes and the associahedra" by Bai http://pirsa.org/17110065

Comment: Similar, shorter talk by Bai https://bhaumik-institute.physics.ucla.edu/sites/default/files/bai.pdf

Comment: An earlier related MO-Q is https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182622/an-intriguing-tapestry-number-triangles-polytopes-grassmannians-and-scatteri

Comment: "The SAGEX Review on Scattering Amplitudes Chapter 7: Positive Geometry of Scattering Amplitudes" by Enrico Herrmann and Jaroslav Trnka https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.13018

Comment: "The positive tropical Grassmannian, the hypersimplex, and the m=2 amplituhedron" by
Tomasz Lukowski, Matteo Parisi, and Lauren K. Williams present (pg. 35) the f-vectors of the associahedra as those of Trop $Gr^{+}_{2,n}$ (https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06164).