# Combinatorics of iterated composition of noncrossing partition polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, polynomials, sequences-and-series, discrete-geometry

A combinatorial problem arises in relating connected and disconnected Green functions associated to a "zero-dimensional" quantum field theory presented by Brezin, Itzykson, Parisi, and Zuber in "[Planar Diagrams](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-59/issue-1/Planar-diagrams/cmp/1103901558.full)" (via Eqn. 31 on p. 42). The first few partition polynomials characterizing this problem are given in OEIS [A338135](https://oeis.org/A338135) for the refined $2-$Narayana polynomials as

1. $G_2  = 1 g_2$
2. $G_4  =  1g_4  +  2 g_2^2$
3. $G_6  =  1g_6  +  6 g_2 g_4 +  5 g_2^3$
4. $G_8  = 1g_8  +  8 g_2 g_6 +  4 g_4^2   +  28 g_2^2 g_4 + 14 g_2^4$
5. $G_{10} = 1g_{10} + 10 g_2 g_8 + 10 g_4 g_6 +  45 g_2^2 g_6 + 45 g_2 g_4^2 + 120 g_2^3 g_4  + 42 g_2^5,$

and Brezin et al. assert $G_{2p}$ enumerates the number of ways $2p$ points on a circle can be connected by non-overlapping clusters of $2q$-plets, which from their multinomial formula can be identified as equivalent to the number of noncrossing partitions (NCP) enumerated and flagged by the nonvanishing partition polynomials $N_n[h_1,h_2,...,h_n]$ of [A134264](https://oeis.org/A134264) or Dyck paths of [A125181](https://oeis.org/A125181) with $h_0=1$ when $h_k$ for $k$ odd is replaced by zero. (The connection to A134264 implies that the row sums of the coefficients are the Fuss-Catalan numbers OEIS [A001764](https://oeis.org/A001764) and that the 'main diagonal' contains the Catalan numbers, A000108. The reduced polynomials generated with all $h_k=t$, give the $2-$Narayana polynomials with the coefficients [A108767](https://oeis.org/A108767), with other combinatorial interpretations.)

This Green function array, as well as A134264 for the NCPs, popped up just recently in "[Connecting Scalar Amplitudes using The Positive Tropical Grassmannian](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.02722)" by Cachazo and Umbert, characterizing scattering amplitudes in certain quantum field theories. C & U give combinatorial interpretations in terms of NCP.

There is a cornucopia of combinatorial/algebraic/geometric constructs associated with all of these the OEIS arrays, but I want to focus on an analytic relation between the NCP and the Green function array that involves an iterative composition or iterated substitution with the NCP polynomials:

**(COMP)**     $\;\;\;\;\;\hat{G}_n(c_1,c_2,...,c_n) = N_n[N_1(c_1),N_2(c_1,c_2),...,N_n(c_1,...,c_n)]= N_n^{(2)}(c_1,c_2,...,c_n).$

For example:

$N_1(u_1) = u_1,$

$N_2(u_1,u_2) = u_1^2 +u_2,$

$N_3(u_1,u_2,u_3) = u_3 + 3 u_2 u_1 + u_1^3.$

Then substituting $N_n$ for $u_n$ in the last equation and expanding gives

$N_3[N_1(c_1),N_2(c_1,c_2) ,N_3(c_1,c_2,c_3)] = (c_3 + 3 c_2 c_1 + c_1^3) + 3(c_1^2 +c_2)(c_1) + c_1^3$

$ = c_3 + 6c_1c_2 + 5c_1^3 = N_3^{(2)}(c_1,c_2,c_3),$

which is the third partition polynomial of the re-indexed Green function array

$\hat{G}_1  = c_1,$

$\hat{G}_2  = c_2  +  2 c_1^2,$

$\hat{G}_3  = c_3  +  6 c_1 c_2 +  5 c_1^3,$

$\hat{G}_4  = c_4  +  8 c_1 c_3 +  4 c_2^2   +  28 c_1^2 c_2 + 14 c_1^4.$

Edit, July 7 and 13, 2022: Start

Lying at the heart of the two algebraic methods of generating these polynomials--by the zeroing out or by the substitutions--are the following theorems that Peter Bala presented in 2008 in the formula section of the reduced array A108767 for the $2-$Narayana polynomials (with some change in notation);

> Define a functional $I$ on formal power series of the form $h(x) = 1 +h_1x + h_2x^2 + ...$ by the following iterative process. Define inductively $F^{(1)}(x) = h(x)$ and $F^{(n+1)}(x) = h(x \cdot F^{(n)}(x))$ for $n \geq 1$. Then set $I(h(x)) = \lim_{n-\to \infty} F^{(n)}(x)$ in the x-adic topology on the ring of formal power series; the operator $I$ may also be defined by $I(h(x)) := \frac{1}{x}(x/h(x))^{(-1)}= f^{(-1)}(x)/x$, the compositional inverse, or series reversion, of $f(x)= x/h(x)$.

> Forming the $m$-fold composition $I^{(m)}(h(x))$ and then replacing $x$ with $x^m$ produces the same result as $I(h(x^m))$.

The main theorem stems from a fixed point-iteration perspective on the deceivingly simple, basic compositional inversion identity

**(INV)**       $\;\;\;\;\;x\; h(f^{(-1)}(x)) = f^{(-1)}(x)$,

and the connection to the NCPs is that

$f^{(-1)}(x) = x\; (1 + N_1(h_1)\; x + N_2(h_1,h_2)\; x^2 + \cdots).$

In fact, **INV** appears as eqn. 29 on p. 41 of Brezin et al.

The $N_n$ polynomials are central to free probability theory (FPT), and the analysis in Brezin et al. is closely related to the calculus of that theory as it relates to random matrix theory and the Cauchy-Hilbert and Stieltjes transforms. A variant of **INV** is a core equation of FPT that appears as eqn. 2.6 (the R-transform) on p. 10 of "[Combinatorics of the categories of noncrossing partitions](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Eslc/s/37%20Chapoton%20Nadeau.pdf)" by Chapoton and Nadeau in which the $2-$Narayana polynomials (A108767) are presented, NCPS are translated into trees, and composition of morphisms are presented as substitutions of trees. The R-transform in FPT defines the relation between free cumulants and moments, analogous to the exp-log definition for the formal cumulants and moments of classical probability theory. The NCP polynomials, or refined Narayana polynomials, $N_n(c_1,...,c_n)$, give the free moments in terms of the free cumulants $c_n$. (This last transformation may be called the R-transform as well, and there are variants of **INV** and the R-transform depending on whether the formulation is couched in terms of power series or Laurent series and on whether the series have a constant summand.)

These results generalize to further substitutions and correspondingly different sets of zeroed indeterminates--as Bala's n-fold composition formula implies--such as other than $h_{3k}$, or other than $h_{4k}$, and so on, generating the refined $m-$Narayana polynomials, reducing to the $m-$Narayana polynomials, reducing in turn to a Fuss-Catalan number sequence, explained by the o.g.f. of the aerated (i.e., with intervening zeros) m-Fuss-Catalan sequence being generated as the compositional inverse in x of $f(x) = x - x^{m+1}$ with $m=1$, the Catalan sequence.

End

Given all the associated combinatorial constructs, one wonders

**Is there a direct combinatorial proof of the self-composition identity (COMP) for the noncrossing partition polynomials?** (Not necessarily restricted to the use of NCPs---there are a multitude of interpretations of these polynomials, such as arcs, lattice paths, and trees as well as dissections of polygons, and some might be more advantageous than others.)

(These results can be couched also in terms of the associahedra partition polynomials of [A133437](https://oeis.org/A133437) and the reciprocal polynomials $R_n$ generated as $1/h(x) = 1 + R_1(h_1) x + R_2(h_1,h_2) x^2 + \cdots$ and in terms of a more general, expansion coefficient array investigated by Schur, so there are lots of connections to be made. An equivalent e.g.f. formulation exists as well.)

Comment: @Peter Taylor: Your convolution result agrees with the alternative method of computation with the associahedra I mentioned, the result I published in the OEIS entry that I must have calculated from the factorial formula and the partition listing in Abramowitz and Stegun (p. 832) a while ago, and C & U; however, your expression for the tenth NCP doesn't agree with the numbers listed from 97 to 138 in Heinz's list for A125181, the Dyck path bijection for the noncrossing partitions nor does the sum of your coefficients give the Fuss-Catalan number.

Comment: Ah! Bug identified and fixed.

Comment: @Peter Taylor, thanks for checking. If you have the code set up and can generate a pdf listing the first 10 polynomials such as the pdf Wolfdieter Lang contributed to https://oeis.org/A036040, publishing that pdf for the OEIS would be helpful for current and future researchers wishing to quickly spot check their analytic results or conjectures related to  A134264, A125181, and/or A338135 (so two pdfs). Be sure to corroborate. your listing with sums of coefficients if you do so.

Comment: In the meantime, [here's a PDF of self-convolved vs even NCPs](https://cheddarmonk.org/papers/ncp_even_vs_recursive.pdf). I'm fairly confident about the way the correspondence must go for $\hat{G}_3$, but for $\hat{G}_4$ I've restricted myself to grouping obvious equivalence classes without speculating on the correspondence between the left and right columns.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, nice diagrams. Could use some explanation for me--I'm busy trying to write up this and related stuff before my notes drop through the cracks as well as tackling some other chores.

Comment: Dyck paths via A125181 and MathWorld make it easy to visualize the effect of zeroing out indeterminates. See https://oeis.org/draft/A354622. It's a Catalan explosion, but it would be nice to have a few more illustrations of the types--not all--of the D. staircases. By type I mean one rep--corresponding to a monomial--of a family of staircases with any pair being equivalent if the steps of one can be moved to horizontally coincide with those of the other without changing step heights. However, some tree rep is likely to be more revealing of the relation between zeroing and substitution.

Comment: The column on the left interprets the outer $N_n$ in COMP as partitioning the $n$ vertices as non-crossing polygons; each of those polygons receives a different colour. Then the inner $N_i$ correspond to partitioning each of the polygons again, preserving the colour.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, sorry, still don't see it. I'm used to a rep as in the bottom fig. of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncrossing_partition where it's easy to see the correspondence with $N_4 = 1 \; u_4 + 4 \; u_1 u_3 + 2 \;  u_2^2 + 6 \;  u_1^2 u_2 +1 \; u_1^4$. My bias: I expect some proliferation rep of that diagram representing COMP with itself and the lower order diagrams (w. vertices 3, 2, 1). Finally, I should see how to translate the final diagram into a multinomial coefficient, such as trees for the factorial. The right column of your figures probably suffices. (Trees, arcs, Dyck paths?)

Comment: https://cheddarmonk.org/papers/ncp_even_vs_recursive_ii.pdf adds monomial labels to the groups and makes the outer $N_n$ colouring more obvious. The outer one corresponds to the thick transparent line/polygon; the inner ones to the narrow heavy lines/polygons.

Comment: For a potential composition rep via trees, see, e.g.,  p. 3 of "An Enumeration Problem for Sequences of n-ary Trees Arising from Algebraic Operads" by Stasiuk (https://harvest.usask.ca/bitstream/handle/10388/11865/STASIUK-THESIS-2019.pdf).

Comment: @PeterTaylor, very nice, much better, but I still need time to mull it over. Would be nice (give a guy an inch and he'll take a mile) to also have another page with just the noncrossing partitions as displayed in the Wiki in one column separated by monomial association for quick comparisons. You should post a copy in the OEIS archive and link to it in the appropriate OEIS entry sometime.

Comment: The first few partition polynomials $c_n=N_n^{(-2)}(m_1,...,m_n)$ that are the compositional inverse of $m_1 = N_n^{(2)}(c_1,...,c_n)$ are posted in "Matryoshka Dolls: Iterated noncrossing partitions, the refined Narayana group, and quantum fields" at https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2022/07/08/iterated-noncrossing-partitions-and-quantum-fields/

Comment: I've added a short introduction to the second document which explains the left column.