# Where can I find  questions motivating important ideas in math?

Tags: teaching, soft-question

I would like questions that demonstrate why a mathematical tool or technique is useful, and which can be used to introduce that idea. Ideally, this would be a compilation of problems organized by the idea they motivate. Does anyone know of such a list? I am thinking of middle school and high school math, but I think such a list would be useful at any level.

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to [fundamental examples](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4994/fundamental-examples), I recommend you read that post as it was very interesting and at least partially answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the Tricki:

http://www.tricki.org

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in middle school/high school math education, I'm sure you already know about Dan Meyer's excellent blog *dy/dan*. In case you haven't, he shares (classroom-tested) lesson ideas and media under the label "[What Can You Do With This?](http://blog.mrmeyer.com/?cat=70)" (the individual posts are also tagged by subject area).

Comment: In fact, I did not know of this blog. Thank you for pointing it out. There are some very nice lesson plans there!