# Centralizer of a maximal split torus

Tags: reference-request, p-adic-groups

Can you help me find a reference for the following fact?

"If $G$ is a quasi-split $p$-adic group and $T$ is a maximal split torus in $G$, then the centralizer of $T$ is a maximal torus in $G$."

Or erase my misconception, if it is not a fact! Thanks!!

Comment: This is not a reference as you are looking for, but see BCnrd's comment at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19830/whenever-i-read-centraliser-of-maximal-split-torus-i-think-of.

Comment: This is a general fact over any field whatsoever, and it is proved as 20.6 in Borel's textbook on linear algebraic groups.