# Examples and Counterexamples in Commutative Algebra

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

There are *Counterexamples in Analysis* and *Counterexamples in Topology*. Is there any similar book for commutative algebra? I want to see some more (counter)examples for Atiyah and MacDonald's book. Let us say "zoo" of rings and modules.

Comment: You may be interested in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29006/counterexamples-in-algebra although 1) it's not a book, and 2) it's not restricted to commutative. There are also a couple of linked/related questions at that page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best I can think of is Harry Clayton Hutchins' "Examples of Commutative Rings" published by UChicago Press (he was a student of Kaplansky). The second part of the book is just a long list of rings satisfying strange properties ("this, this and this, but not that"). The one difference with counterexamples in top is the lack of a good index/table putting everything together, so it can be (quite) hard to find a specific example.